# Correct way to remotely restart a computer using System.Management.Automation

Tags: powershell, .net-core, powershell-remoting

I'm using the System.Management.Automation and System.Management.Automation.Runspaces packages in an attempt to remotely restart a computer, and then wait for that computer to become available again. However whatever i do results in the runspace being in a broken state. Is there any guidance on how to do this in C# using the latest versions of the System.Management.Automation packages?

Sorry if this is too cryptic/vague, I'm fairly new to writing anything in C#/.net and any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: What cmdlet are you sending to your powershell instance? Normally, on PS, you would just do [`Restart-Computer host01 -Wait`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/restart-computer?view=powershell-7.2) for this.

Comment: "whatever i do results in the runspace being in a broken state." - can you show us an example of the "whatever" that leaves the runspace in a broken state?

Answer (score 0):

I normally use PowerShell to restart a computer and wait for it to comeback online before the script continues. I've left a snippet for you to use.

```
$ServerName = 'Computer1'

#Local Server Admin Account
[STRING] $LocalUser = "Administrator" #Obviously Change Account
[STRING] $LocalPassword = "Password01" #Obviously Change Password
$LocalSecurePassword = $LocalPassword | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$LocalCredentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $LocalUser, $LocalSecurePassword

#Restart Server
Restart-Computer -ComputerName "$ServerName" -Credential $LocalCredentials -Impersonation 3 -Authentication 6 -Force
Start-Sleep -s 180
#Wait for Server to Restart
    Do {(Write-Host "The Server $ServerName is restarting"),(Start-Sleep -seconds 60)}
    Until ((Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -ComputerName $ServerName -Credential $LocalCredentials -Impersonation 3 -Authentication 6 | Where-Object{$_.Name -eq 'RemoteRegistry'}).State -eq 'Running')
                
Write-Host "Remove PS Session"
Get-PSSession | Remove-PSSession
                
Start-Sleep -s 60
#Exit
```